# Visual Studio 2017 build fails

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, build, xamarin-studio

I am not Xamarin developer, I've just installed a VS2017 (Community 7.4.3) on my mac and I am trying to build project from my co-worker. But I get this error:

"/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/5.8.1/lib/mono/xbuild/Xamarin/iOS/Xamarin.iOS.CSharp.targets" was not found"

And indeed there is no "Xamarin" directory in "lib/mono/xbuild". I've looked for solutions already, but most of them was to update VS, but mine's up to date

Comment: Does your system have XCode installed?

Comment: Yes it has it installed

Comment: Sounds like a faulty install. Try re-install it. Alternatively try installing mono separately from http://www.mono-project.com/download/stable/